Solutions of an ode with Wronskian zero?
It is well known that in order to check linear independence (dependence) in a set of solutions of an ode, one computes the Wronskian of such functions and, if it is different from zero, the solutions are linearly independent (li).
It is also known that there can be li functions whose Wronskian is zero, even in the whole set of reals $\mathbb{R}$ (see for instance here).
My question is the link between the two statements: If one has a fundamental set of solutions of an ode, do they always have to yield Wronskian different from zero?

Let's only consider functions on $[0,1]$. We definitely know linear dependence $\implies$ Wronskian = $0$ identically.
The contrapositive of this statement is Wronskian non-zero at one point in $[0,1]$ $\implies$ the functions are linearly independent.
Now given $n$ linearly independent functions $f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\in \mathcal{C}^{n}[0,1]$ ($n$ times continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$) consider the Wronskian $$W(f_1, \dots, f_n, y) = a_n y^n + \dots + a_0 y =0 $$
Also observe $a_n= W(f_1, \cdots, f_n)$ (look at the matrix of we're finding determinant of above).
Each of $f_i$ satisfies this equation (when replacing $y$ with $f_i$). So there exists a $n$-th order linear homogeneous ODE corresponding  to any set $n$ linearly independent equations. This is not unique because I can multiply both sides with a positive continuous function and still the solution set won't change.
This helped me to create this table:



If $f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\in \mathcal{C}^{n}[a,b]$ are
$W=0$ at all points
There are points $x_0,x_1\in [0,1]$  $W(x_{0})\neq 0$ but $W(x_{1})=0$
$W \neq 0$ at all points




linearly dependent
always
not possible
not possible


linearly independent
We have examples like $\{x^3, x^2|x|\}$. Not sure the above ODE gives us here...
The $a_n=W$ is zero at some point and non-zero at others, this type of equation $$ W(f_{1},f_{2},\dots,f_{n},y) $$ is called singular $n$-th order homogeneous linear ODE
Divide the equation by $W$, then $$\frac{W(f_1, \dots, f_n, y)}{W(f_1, \dots, f_n)}$$ is a equation where coefficient of $y^n$ is $1$ and the set is still solution to this ODE. So the set is solution to a monic $n$-th order linear ODE in this case.



Now to answer your main question (I think), given a monic equation like this $y^{n}+\dots+ a_0 y =0$ if we have $n$ solutions $f_1, \dots, f_n$ we have a bijection of the solution space with $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the map is "evaluation of derivatives at $x=a$" $$ \begin{align} \{ \text{solutions }y \}  &\cong \mathbb{R}^{n}\\ y &\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}  y(a)\\ y^{\prime} (a)\\ \vdots \\ y^{n}(a) \end{bmatrix} \end{align} $$
Say we have $n$ solutions and their Wronskian $W=0$ at a point $a\in [0,1]$ the bijection of the solution space with initial conditions for $x=a$ says the corresponding initial conditions are linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence the solutions are linearly dependent as functions $\iff$ $W$ is zero identically.
We conclude in this case of considering functions that are solutions to monic linear ODEs, solutions are linearly independent $\iff$ the Wronskian is not zero at every point.
Reference: Gerald's book https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ (there is a PDF available freely). There is also a argument about the uniqueness of the monic equation for the $W\neq 0$ case.
(I think what I am calling "monic", is called regular ODEs?)

You should be more explicit on the conditions under which solutions are linearly independent $\iff$ the Wronskian is not zero at every point is valid. Here is a counterexample: $x^2$ and $x^3$ are linearly independent solutions to the differential equation $y''-\frac{4}{x}y'+\frac{6}{x^2}y=0,$ but the Wronskian $W[x^2,x^3]=x^4$ is not zero at every point.

In your counterexample @Gonçalo the domain (of solutions $y$) is expected to be in $(0, \infty)$ (because the coefficients are not defined at $0$) so let's fix that domain (could have also chosen negative reals). Now in that case $W=x^4>0$ on this domain. Therefore this does not contradict solutions to monic homogeneous linear ODEs are linearly independent $\iff$ Wronskian is non-zero at all points (in the domain we're working with, I should have been clearer about that I think!)
